# Is there a way to combine tabling with clause?

Tags: prolog

In my program, I use a simple recursive `clause/2` to track my proving.

```
prove(X):-
    clause(X, B),
    B == true.
prove((X1, X2)):-
    prove(X1),
    prove(X2).
prove(X):-
    X \= true,
    X \= (_, _),
    clause(X, B),
    write(X), write(' <= '), write(B), nl,
    prove(B).
```

What's more, I'm trying to use `tabling` to solve the exchangeability/transitivity problems. (I'm talking about `f(a)=b <=> f(b)=a`, `f(a)=b, f(b)=c => f(a)=c`, etc).

I know using transistive closure or a decorated predicate can help to solve this. However, I'm working on a lot of rules. If I do the same stuff for each group of rules, it would be a huge workload for me, and indeed, contributes to a lot of bugs right now.

However, firstly `clause` is tracing back to `start_tabling`.

```
[1]  ?- prove(segment_equal(c,d,a,b)).
segment_equal(c,d,a,b) <= start_tabling(user:segment_equal(c,d,a,b),segment_equal tabled(c,d,a,b))
```

Secondly, it will raise Errors.

```
ERROR: No permission to access private_procedure `'$tbl_variant_table'/3'
```

**So I'm wondering if I can use `tabling` to save my codes and track the procedure at the same time? Or any other better practice?**

PS: If background provides any help, I'm working on a geometry automated theorem prover, as we known, those basic rules appear in many theorems, like *segment equal*, *angle equal*, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use the `predicate_property/2` predicate to exclude which predicates that should not be traced. For example, the following meta-interpreter will only trace calls to dynamic predicates:

```
prove(X) :-
    clause(X, B),
    B == true.
prove((X1, X2)) :-
    prove(X1),
    prove(X2).
prove(X) :-
    clause(X, B),
    (   predicate_property(B, dynamic) ->
        write(X), write(' <= '), write(B), nl
    ;   true
    ),
    prove(B).
```

Depending on the used Prolog system, there may be other reflection predicates that would allow you to filter what should be traced. E.g. only predicates defined in whitelisted files.

Comment: Thank you so much!